# Puting script labels in a module problems

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, fix-my-code, jquery, custom-module

I'm trying to put a jQuery pluin in a module which I have developed. When I do it, it doesn't work. The code where I put this labels is this:

```
<?php

   // no direct access
   defined('_JEXEC') or die;
   JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::root . 'modules/mod_k2_users/tmpl/Default/DataTables-1.10.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css');
   JHtml::_('script', JUri::root . 'modules/mod_k2_users/tmpl/Default/DataTables-1.10.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js');
   JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
   $params = K2HelperUtilities::getParams('com_k2');
   $limitstart = JRequest::getInt('limitstart');
?>

<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#tUsuarios').dataTable( {
    "searching":true,
    "paging":   true,
    "ordering": true,
    "info":     false
   } );
 } );
</script>



 <div id="k2ModuleBox<?php echo $module->id; ?>" class="k2UsersBlock<?php if($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')) echo ' '.$params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?>">
    <table id="tUsuarios" class="display">
     <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Nivel</th>
        <th>País</th>
        <th>Votos</th>
        <th>Skype</th>
        <th>Hangaout</th>
        <th>Facetime</th>
        <th>Correo</th>

     </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>

       <?php foreach($users as $key=>$user): 


    ?>
      <tr class="<?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even"; if(count($users)==$key+1) echo ' lastItem'; ?>">
       <td> 
        <?php if($userName): ?>
        <a class="ubUserName" rel="author" href="<?php echo $user->link; ?>" title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($user->Nombre); ?>">
            <?php echo $user->Nombre; ?>
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
     </td>
     <td>

     </td>
     <td>
        <?php if($userName): ?>
        <a class="ubUserName" rel="author" href="<?php echo $user->link; ?>" title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($user->Nivel); ?>">
            <?php echo $user->Nivel; ?>
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
     </td>
     <td>
        <?php if($userName): ?>
        <a class="ubUserName" rel="author" href="<?php echo $user->link; ?>" title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($user->Pais); ?>">
            <?php echo $user->Pais; ?>
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
     </td>
     <td>
        <?php if($userName): ?>
        <a class="ubUserName" rel="author" href="<?php echo $user->link; ?>" title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($user->Nombre); ?>">
            <?php echo $user->Nombre; ?>
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
     </td>
     <td>
        <?php if($userName): ?>
        <a class="ubUserName" rel="author" href="<?php echo $user->link; ?>" title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($user->Skype); ?>">
            <?php echo $user->Skype; ?>
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
     </td>
     <td>
        <?php if($userName): ?>
        <a class="ubUserName" rel="author" href="<?php echo $user->link; ?>" title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($user->Google); ?>">
            <?php echo $user->Google; ?>
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
     </td>
     <td>
        <?php if($userName): ?>
        <a class="ubUserName" rel="author" href="<?php echo $user->link; ?>" title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($user->Facebook); ?>">
            <?php echo $user->Facebook; ?>
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
     </td>
      <td>
        <?php if($userName): ?>
                <span class="ubUserName" rel="author" title="<?php echo K2HelperUtilities::cleanHtml($user->Email); ?>">
                <?php echo $user->Email;?>
            </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
     </td>



    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>    
</table>
```

What I'm doing wrong?. Thanks so much

Comment: What exactly does not work? BTW `defined('_JEXEC') or die;` should be on the top of file.

Comment: This jquery plugin should sort a table.It's the table jquery which you can see here: http://www.datatables.net/, and just I see the css, not more thins as on the website appears.Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that `jquery.dataTables.js` in not included? Can you provide the link to the page where do you use this module? 

Also I think that you do not need to include `jquery.js` - your template includes it.

Comment: The link it's this: http://rmh.citafgsr.info/index.php/servicios/intercambio-lingueistico

Answer (score 1):

You've made a mistake in your code.

You're using `jquery` instead of `jQuery`. @Dmitry has already showed you the code you need to use which you could have copied ans pasted so I'm not sure how that went wrong.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#tUsuarios').dataTable( {
        "searching":true,
        "paging": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": false
    });
});
```

I would also suggest you import your CSS and JS files correctly, so replace:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://rmh.citafgsr.info/modules/mod_k2_intercambios/tmpl/Default/DataTables-1.10.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://rmh.citafgsr.info/modules/mod_k2_intercambios/tmpl/Default/DataTables-1.10.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

with:

```
<?php
    JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::root . 'modules/mod_k2_intercambios/tmpl/Default/DataTables-1.10.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css');
    JHtml::_('script', JUri::root . 'modules/mod_k2_intercambios/tmpl/Default/DataTables-1.10.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js');
?>
```

Please read the Joomla documentation before doing things else you will run into more problems and get a better understanding of things

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you to do the following:

1. Move `defined('_JEXEC') or die;` to the top of your file.
2. Do not include `jquery.js` in your module, because your template already includes it. You should also disable duplicate jQuery inclusion in your template. If you watch the source code of your page you will see that `jquery.js` in included several times.
3. Try to change `$` in your script to jQuery, like this:

---

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('#tUsuarios').dataTable( {
        "searching":true,
        "paging":   true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info":     false
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't understand the 3rd point

Comment: What exactly? Just change `$` to `jQuery` in your JS code.

Comment: Exactly, if this code it's between <script>, Must I keep these labels?. Regards

Comment: Keep everything, just change `$` to `jQuery` in your code between `<script>` :)

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: Any JS error there?

Comment: How can I see the JS error?. Regards

Comment: @zoit - If you're able to develop a module, then I'm sure you've heard of a [browser console](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=browser+console).

Comment: I have this error after watching the console:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

Comment: @Lodder, when I do what you said, after put online the module the page turns white and I don't know why. I edit the code and I post the new code so you can take a look about it. Thanks so much

Comment: A white/blank page means there are errors but you have error reporting disabled. You need to turn it on

Comment: I have turned it on and when I put available this module, all the page is white so I can't see the error reporting. Thanks @Lodder

Comment: error reporting is enabled in the Joomla global configuration. Please read the Joomla documentation

Comment: I did it, you can check it.

Comment: @Lodder, the error which I get it's this: Strict Standards: Non-static method plgSystemYt::nameOfSJTemplate() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/vhosts/citafgsr.info/rmh/plugins/system/ytshortcodes/ytshortcodes.php on line 93 Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'root' in /var/www/vhosts/citafgsr.info/rmh/modules/mod_k2_users/tmpl/Default/default.php on line 12

Comment: The strict standards error is not an issue. This is because of the changes in PHP 5.4+. You can disable strict error by setting error reporting to **simple**. The fatal error is something to do with the K2 module which you need to contact the developers about.

Comment: With the developers of the module?, if it's this the case, I was who developed the module. Because the mistake is here: JHtml::_('script', JUri::root . 'modules/mod_k2_intercambios/tmpl/Default/DataTables-1.10.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js');Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing that your js and css files are located in tmpl(template folder),

> try keeping them in separate folder

and 
another thing is that did u intentionally made folder name in upper case ?
like

**Default instead of default** ?

> try changing folder name in lowercase, sometime it becomes a huge
>   issue in server.